# how can I run a command as superuser

Tags: linux, sudo

I can log in as super user and run a program, now I want to check the status without logging in as super user.

example:

```
dev01:~$ sudo su
dev01# forever list
info:    Forever processes running
<some more output>
dev01# exit
dev01:~$ sudo forever list
sudo: forever: command not found
```

How can I check the program status without logging in as supper user ?

I do not have '`su`' password but I am a sudoer.

Comment: welcome to U&L, your question is somehow unclear, whatever interactive process ran by forever command, thay are likely to be shut when you exit root session.

Comment: 1) what is the path of forever command ? 2) it should be added, with full path in sudoer.conf file.

Comment: let me explain a bit. I have a ssh object and using that ssh object to perform server running status. As the server running as superuser I am not able to check the server status without root password. How can I gat the info with sudo access. Forever is a demon process and added to path.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` is probably configured to override your `$PATH`, and `forever` isn't in that path. There are a few solutions:

1. Give `sudo` the full path to the command: `sudo /usr/local/sbin/forever` (or whatever the path is).
2. Change (or probably ask your sysadmin to change) the `sudo` configuration to include the right directory. If changing it yourself, you'd use `visudo`, though beware that breaking the `sudo` config may leave you locked out.
3. Use `sudo -s` or `sudo -i` to get a root shell, then set `$PATH` if needed. Finally run the command. This defeats `sudo`'s logging of the run command, so really isn't preferred.

Some of the above may not be permitted by the `sudo` config. Then you're just left with "ask the sysadmin to fix it."

Comment: Thanks for the update. It make sense now. I have to try out the options.